# How can I get Loged in user details from different Mdels as arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying to integrate a payment system in my Django project and I models for profile, and submitted.
The issue is that I want a situation where when a user clicks on pay button the system should check whether he/she has submitted application and if so; grab the username, email, phone, amount and pass them as arguments into my process_payment view where the payment is going to be done.

here is code for Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    applicant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    nation = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=NATION, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', upload_to ='profile_images')
```

here is code for Scholarship model:

```
class Submitted(models.Model):
   applicant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   application = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, editable = False, default=uuid.uuid4)
   confirm = models.BooleanField()
   approved = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.application == str(uuid.uuid4())
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.applicant

def __str__(self):
    return f'Application Number: {self.application}-{self.applicant}'
```

Here is my view code:

```
@login_required(login_url='user-login')
def scholarship_detail(request, pk):
    data = Scholarship.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method=='POST':
    
    
    
        applicant=  request.user
        email = 'henry@gmail.com'
        amount = 2
        phone = 8034567
        return redirect(str(process_payment(applicant,email,amount,phone)))
    
        
   else:
      form = PaymentForm()

  ctx={
    'scholarship':data
  }
  return render(request, 'user/scholarship.html', ctx)
```

How can this logic be implemented efficiently because my trial is saying process_payment() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'email', 'amount', and 'phone'. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `process_payment` parameters to a dictionary(context) and return `process_payment`. then all other operations will happen inside `process_payment`

```
@login_required(login_url='user-login')
def scholarship_detail(request, pk):
    data = Scholarship.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method=='POST':
    
    
    
        applicant=  request.user
        email = 'henry@gmail.com'
        amount = 2
        phone = 8034567
        context = {'applicant':applicant, 'email':email, 'amount':amount, phone} # Add to context. this will grab all the details into `process_payment` view
        return process_payment(request, context)
    
        
   else:
      form = PaymentForm()

  ctx={
    'scholarship':data
  }
  return render(request, 'user/scholarship.html', ctx)
```

`process_payment` view or function will look similar to:

```
def process_payment(request, newContext={}):
   print(newContext)
   # Process the payment here 
   return render(request, 'payment.html', newContext)
```

This should do the trick, but let me know if you have more questions

Comment: your answer worked 95% the only error I am getting now is 'module' object is not callable. I don't know whether it is as a result of my environment configuration. You may wish to help again

Comment: can you share a screenshort/url of the full error message?

Comment: I can share but How can I do it in the comment section here.

Comment: upload the screenshot to your google drive or cloudinary and share the url here

Comment: can we chat here.

Comment: yes we can chat here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244934/discussion-between-bruno-and-apollos).